How to avoid "key error" in python for loop?
I am new to python and I am trying to conduct multiple PubMed searches and save the number of results in a CSV file. The code I have right now will not run uless I remove my for loop. I would like the code to run through a column of "Terms" provided in a CSV file, but I don't know what location to place the for loop, and I don't know how to...I guess set the variable for the loop to run. Here is what I have that produces the key error:
import requests
import time
import pandas as pd

def get_pubmed_results_count(search_terms, delay=1):
    base_url = "https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi"
    results = {}

    for term in search_terms:
        # Define parameters for the API request
        params = {
            "db": "pubmed",
            "term": term,
            "retmode": "json"
        }

        try:
            # Make the request to the PubMed API
            response = requests.get(base_url, params=params)
            response.raise_for_status()

            # Parse the response
            data = response.json()
            count = data['esearchresult']['count']
            results[term] = count

        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            print(f"Error retrieving data for term '{term}': {e}")
            results[term] = None

        # Respectful delay between requests
        time.sleep(delay)

    return results

# Example usage

df_searchterms = pd.read_csv('search1.csv')
print(df_searchterms)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for index, row in df_searchterms.iterrows():
        search_terms = (row['Term']) 
        result_counts = get_pubmed_results_count(search_terms)
    
    for term, count in result_counts.items():
       df_results = pd.DataFrame(result_counts.items(), columns=['term','count'])
       print (df_results)
       df_results.to_csv('TestRestults1.csv', index=False)

And here is what my search terms data frame looks like:
 Term
0   APOE AND Alzheimer's
1  PSEN1 AND Alzheimer's
2  PSEN2 AND Alzheimer's
3    APP AND Alzheimer's
4    CLU AND Alzheimer's

My question is, how to I get this to run without the keyerror?

Don't comment out the code that's getting the error. Post the problem code, and include the full traceback of the error.

Is the code after the for loop supposed to be inside the loop? If not, search_terms will just be the value from the last row of the df.

Are you trying to make a list of all the search terms in the df? You're just setting it to the value from one row, not a list of all rows.

If you want a list of all the terms, use search_terms = list(df_searchterms['Term']). You don't need a for loop.

@Barmar "Is the code after the for loop supposed to be inside the loop?" - There's more than one for loop, so to clarify, you're talking about for index, row, right? I would say the same thing.

Ok, I edited my question and included the code that does not run....and I see your latest comment will probably work, so let me try that right now!

Yes, that's it! search_terms = list(df_searchterms['Term']) was the answer. Thank you @Barmar

get_pubmed_results_count() expects the argument to be a list. search_terms is a single string.

result_counts is just the counts from the last call to get_pubmed_results_count(). So you need for term, count in result_counts.items(): to be inside for index, row in df_searchterms.iterrows():

I notice that your variable search_terms is just a list with one string inside...
if you want a list of a entire columm you need to do:
search_terms = df_searchterms[""APOE AND Alzheimer's]

I can't try to run your code by myself bcs you dont give the "search1.csv" file, but you can add a counter and run the entire list
if the for continues to execute just 1 time, plz try:
for i in range(len(search_terms)):
    # Define parameters for the API request
    params = {
        "db": "pubmed",
        "term": search_terms[i],
        "retmode": "json"

or give us a example of your "search1.csv"
Edit: It took me so long to write a good answer that they said what I thought in the coments, and I need more reputation points

Hello, yes, I did include the info from search1.csv
